# Scrapy crawl goes to next page and comes back

Tags: python, scrapy

As mentioned in the title, my spider goes to page2 and comes back to page1. So the order is 1-2-1. I have no idea where to look.

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css("div.z7ntrt-0.cLlfW.s1a29zcm-11.ggOMjb"):
       yield {
            "name": products.css("a.link-detail::attr(title)").get(),
            "link": products.css("a.link-detail").attrib["href"],
            "source": products.css("div.tag::text").get()
       }

    next_page = response.css("a.s1pk8cwy-4.eSWEIV::attr(href)").get()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page_link=response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: Is there a third page? If there isn't then it is logical to put the previous page in the same tag. You can keep a set or a list of the visited pages and check against it before parsing. If there is a third page then you can still use the previous solution and go to the next tag if the check fails, or make sure you look for the right tag.

Comment: It did not solve my problem. I tried many tags, they worked in the same way. 1-2-1 order.

Comment: Using a set of the visited urls didn't work?

Comment: @SwiftyQA there's not enough information, can you add to url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the class name you are using is used as both the forward arrow and the back arrow in the pagination section of the webpage.

[image]

However, the current page element seems to have a unique value for it's
class attribute and it is consistently the same on each page, so using Xpath we can isolate the current page and then use the `following-sibling` directive to get the page immediately after the current page.

I have tested this and can confirm that it does work as expected.

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for products in response.css("div.z7ntrt-0.cLlfW.s1a29zcm-11.ggOMjb"):
       yield {
            "name": products.css("a.link-detail::attr(title)").get(),
            "link": products.css("a.link-detail").attrib["href"],
            "source": products.css("div.tag::text").get()
       }
    next_page = response.xpath(
        '//a[contains(@class,"ctiKSh")]/following-sibling::a/@href'
    ).get()
    if next_page is not None:
        next_page_link=response.urljoin(next_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=next_page_link, callback= self.parse)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! I am a beginner so I missed that, but now I learned it thanks to you. Appreciated the work!